# User answering the question after it is closed

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, closed-questions

I recently [closed a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23652877/1542290) at **11:13:15Z** and user answered at **11:14:40Z**

How did he do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a [4 hour grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79434/why-was-an-answer-allowed-on-a-question-that-was-merged-into-another-one/79457#79457) where someone with the editor open can still post their answers after a question has been closed.

This is by design; a feature, not a bug.

The user does get notified when a post is closed, and the *Post Your Answer* button is disabled when the notification is received. Either the notification hadn't come in (yet), or the user was really determined and re-enabled the button. The mobile view of the site doesn't get the notifications at all, and as a consequence you won't need to tamper with the button either.

Also see [Post answer after question closed and banner shows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160753/post-answer-after-question-closed-and-banner-shows)

Comment: Didn't knew that :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Didn't know that :) *

Comment: @Ruddy can't edit anymore :)

Comment: Or the user was using the mobile site.  I think the mobile site does not get the update that the question was closed until the page is reloaded so the button never gets disabled.  Although they could have changed that when they rolled out the new API and the Android/iOS Apps

Comment: @psubsee2003: ah, yes, the mobile view. Perhaps the mobile apps as well.

Comment: Inspect Element FTW!