# Give high-rep users immunity from closure when answering

Tags: feature-request

One thing that's an endless source of frustration on SO is having a detailed, strong answer to a question written and ready to submit, only to be rejected because other users have decided that, since they don't like the question, others shouldn't be able to answer it. My personal preference would be to do away with the vote-to-close system entirely, but since that's likely to be unpopular, how about giving users with sufficiently high rep, and/or users with one or more gold badges in one of the original tags on the question, immunity from closure when answering?

Part of the reason I think this would be useful is that, when a question has been wrongly closed by people who misunderstand it and think it's unanswerable, the best way of refuting that and getting it reopened without it getting re-closed again, is to provide a good answer that shows why the question is actually interesting and worthy of being answered. High-rep users and/or experts in the questions tags should be trusted to make this judgement call.

Another tangential idea: Allow any user who had started writing an answer (drafts are kept server-side to some extent, right (?), so this should be checkable) to submit the answer even if the question is closed by the time they hit submit.

Comment: "*Allow any user who had started writing an answer (drafts are kept server-side to some extent, right (?), so this should be checkable) to submit the answer even if the question is closed by the time they hit submit.*" This is already possible, to some extent, though I think the grace period was shortened from a few hours to a few minutes. There's a question about it lying somewhere around here on Meta.

Comment: @Cupcake: If that's the case, the time limit is probably way too short to write a decent answer in.

Comment: Examples are needed <- and as a bonus, if they truly were wrongly closed meta-effect will gladly reopen them for you.

Comment: When you have a gold tag badge, what prevents you from reopening that question?

Comment: [category #3](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/839601)?

Comment: @Cupcake the question you're looking for is likely [User answering the question after it is closed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254820/839601), it refers "[4 hour grace period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79434/why-was-an-answer-allowed-on-a-question-that-was-merged-into-another-one/79457#79457)"

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I have some gold tag badges and I've never been able to reopen questions unilaterally. I seem to get one vote just like everybody else.

Answer (score 15):

As far as your feature-request goes I disagree with the idea because when 5 people have voted to close against 1 (*you*) thinking it's a good question you probably need a little break...The reputation should not matter in that case because voting to close requires at least 3K+ and [people don't close questions for fun](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261419/how-can-we-encourage-close-voters-to-use-their-powers).

It's a democratic choice when a question gets closed. It takes 5 people to close a question ( [unless it's a duplicate different restrictions apply](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers?lq=1)). 
There is a very little chance that 5 people in your favourite tags (c, c++, linux) will misunderstand the question, misinterpret it and wrongly vote-to-close it. *Can you provide an example of such a question?*

I guess the close reason is also quite important here. Some questions (primarily opinion based and too broad) are hard to get re-opened. Those are basically off-topic no matter what because they attract opinion based answers not based on actual facts.

But when a question is closed as "Unclear what you're asking" you may be able to get it re-opened if you edit it and make sense out of it.

Remember, you can always **edit the question** (*don't drastically change the question so it matches your answer*) and ask for it to be re-opened. Meanwhile, save your answer in a text file for later use. Do that only if you really, I mean REALLY think that the question does deserve to be re-opened.

Comment: an option worth considering if attempt to reopen fails is to re-post (possibly improved version of) the question and [instantly self answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/instant-self-answer/info "what's this") it

Comment: @gnat I wouldn't do that - some people may consider that rep-whoring (*not me*) but if something has gotten closed in the first place why would you repost? ygh this can get tricky.. The truth is you can always get more attention when trying to re-open a wrongly closed on-topic question by mentioning it on MSO

Comment: agree, reopen looks preferable to me too. I thought about self-answer option only after reading some comments here complaining about difficulties in reopening

Comment: I think what @gnat suggested would be rep-whoring because it doesn't help OP (the OP probably won't even see the new question), which was the whole point in answering in the first place.

Comment: @R.. to help OP see the re-posted question, one can simply refer it in comments (closure prevents only answers, comments still can be added)

Comment: @gnat: Indeed, I suppose that works.

Comment: @mehow: I don't have examples handy, but it's happened a number of times every year since I've been on SO. In most cases I eventually got the question reopened at least long enough to post. It happens most often when the question seems to have an opinion component to it and seems inflammatory, but also admits objective technical answers which avoid those pitfalls, but sometimes it's just a matter where it's wrongly getting labelled as duplicate because non-experts in the topic don't see the subtle difference from an existing question.

Comment: @R.. regarding incorrect duplicates, editing these to reopen is [technically simple](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773 "see eg sections 2 and 3 here"). But you may get in trouble if asker refuses to collaborate (_hey, rollback your edit, I didn't mean what you added_) - if this happens, a convenient way out could be to repost your own version of their question with desired adjustments and instantly self-answer it

Answer (score 6):

Step one when you see a question that is closed or about to be closed but which shouldn't be, is to **edit it** so that no one thinks it should be closed.

You [commented on me how's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261492/give-high-rep-users-immunity-from-closure-when-answering#comment48183_261500):

> the question seems to have an opinion component to it and seems inflammatory, but also admits objective technical answers which avoid those pitfalls, but sometimes it's just a matter where it's wrongly getting labelled as duplicate because non-experts in the topic don't see the subtle difference from an existing question.

Edit. Edit the subtleties into explicitudes. Edit out the inflammatory opinionfuzz. Edit edit edit; remove marble until everyone can see the angel that you see.

Closed posts go into a review queue for reopening after they're edited. You should add your own reopen vote as well.

*Then* post your answer.

Comment: I would add that after a little practice, reopening edits become rather easy to make, at least in questions that are solid and sane at their core. [Atwood's transform](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124930/165773 "what's this") is not a rocket science