# I should be allowed to answer closed questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, closed-questions

Too many times I have read a question and gone away to write and test a solution, only to come back to find that the question has been suspended, usually because it is *unclear what you're asking* or *too broad*

The problem is often that the post has been made by a non-native English speaker, so I will also have spent a while untangling the language to establish the real question, and rewriting and editing the OP's original words

While I can understand people's frustration in seeing a badly-written question from someone who understands only that Stack Overflow will fix anything, I don't see an advantage to wasting an hour or so's work by prohibiting me from posting the solution that I have created

Yes, I can vote to reopen a question, but unlike the blanket close privilege that I have on duplicate questions, I still need others to agree with me that it should be reopened

Given Stack Overflow's renowned failure to properly resurrect old posts, even if the question is changed beyond all recognition, I suggest that it should be possible to post a solution to any suspended post. After all, by insurrection I may post anything as an edit to the question or, god forbid, as a sequence of comments

What is this prohibition aiming to achieve? Can it be abolished?

Comment: Comments [archived](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/114779/discussion-on-question-by-borodin-i-should-be-allowed-to-answer-closed-questions). Please continue this discussion via the answers or in chat.

Comment: Related: [Give high rep users immunity from closure when answering](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261492)

Answer (score 32):

> The problem is often that the post has been made by a non-native
>   English speaker, so I will also have spent a while untangling the
>   language to establish the real question, and rewriting and editing the
>   OP's original words

That's actually really great - Questions that get edited after being put on hold (the process you call here "suspended") get pushed into the Reopen queue, where 3000+ rep users can determine whether the question now meets the quality standards of the site - and when they conclude that it does it will get reopened.

> Yes, I can vote to reopen a question, but unlike the blanket close
>   privilege that I have on duplicate questions, I still need others to
>   agree with me that it should be reopened

And that's good, because we all curate this site together, so that judgement call isn't yours alone to make. It's barely anyone's, only moderators and Stack Exchange employees can do that. And from what I hear and from what the theory of moderation says, even the people who can do that are reluctant to do it unless its a fringe case. Generally speaking, the curation of this site is by most fundamental design a team effort - of everyone.

> Given Stack Overflow's renowned failure to properly resurrect old
>   posts, even if the question is changed beyond all recognition, I
>   suggest that it should be possible to post a solution to any suspended
>   post. After all, by insurrection I may post anything as an edit to the
>   question or, god forbid, as a sequence of comments

I never felt that, and I'm not sure this is supported by evidence; can you maybe provide some concrete examples? We can fix all of this retroactively when it turns out to be legitimately wrongly closed.

**To be clear:** If you could answer any closed question, then the facility of closing a question would be all but irrelevant. The primary purpose of closing a question is to stop it from receiving (mostly poorly thought out or crapshoot) answers while its problems are being fixed.

> What is this prohibition aiming to achieve? Can it be abolished?

It's one of our primary quality control mechanisms. Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow in particular get loads of really, *really* bad questions. Not necessarily questions that nobody can crank out a half-related boilerplate answer to, but questions that should never be answered. Remember the primary purpose of this is to create a repository of knowledge, not to satisfy the instant gratification demands of every last user.

**In conclusion:** I don't think you should be able to answer closed questions - they're closed for a reason. If you really care that much about a closed question, get it reopened.

Comment: *"Questions that get edited after being put on hold (the process you call here "suspended") get pushed into the Reopen queue"* No. Questions are marked "on hold" immediately, and I have *never* known a question to be reopened after I have edited it

Comment: @Borodin Your assertion that the statement is false doesn't make it false.  The reopen queue and how its fed is a well established mechanism of the site.  The fact that you apparently haven't made edits significant enough to merit the reopening of a question (or haven't noticed the subsequent reopening, which is more likely) doesn't infer your assertion.

Comment: @Borodin Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen). Thats the reopen queue, and you can participate in it. Maybe link to 2 or 3 questions you edited to get them reopened? I can almost guarantee all of them have had a review in the reopen queue.

Comment: *"Remember the primary purpose of this is to create a repository of knowledge, not to satisfy the instant gratification demands of every last user"* I often express the exact same sentiment in my own comments and posts. However, the core of my question still hasn't been answered

Comment: And that's the problem with SO. The site is flooded with so much crap that a 90k user hasn't seen a single good quality question and therefore doesn't know what they look like.

Comment: @Borodin You are asking for one of our two primary curation mechanisms to be abolished because you think your own judgement at what a question should be here should supercede a community consensus. I don't think that that will ever come to pass, as it is completly contrary to the fundamental purpose of this site.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats

Comment: @Shog9 - Would it be possible to get a line at the bottom of the Closure statistics area which was just totals? For example, calculating the overall % reopened from that section seems a little tedious at present.

Comment: @Magisch: *"You are asking for one of our two primary curation mechanisms to be abolished"* No, that would be foolish. Had I realised that the *only* measure taken against posters who wrote an question marked `[on hold]` was that they may not receive answers then I would have asked a different question. It's bizarre how there are so many ways in which SO seems broken, and requires me to dig into the inner workings to fathom what some things mean. It's also disingenuous to be followed by people who will wave pom-poms for SO and ignore anything that I have to say.

Comment: @Borodin I think you're taking this too seriously. You asked a feature request question and its not that well recieved. Its not like this counts against you.

Comment: @Borodin The fact that people disagree (strongly) with your proposal doesn't mean they're ignoring you.  If this question had no answers, votes, or comments, *that* would be ignoring you.  Lots of people posting rather engaged feedback on your proposal is literally the opposite of being ignored.

Comment: @Magisch: SO documentation is abysmal. I came to the site expecting things to be intuitive and obvious. But there is an underworld of *meta* which doesn't interest me, but seems to be vital for anyone who uses the system. That's up to the creators, of course, for they are gods, and this is their playroom. But if you need to struggle with trolls and cliques on a web site that supposed to be a bare and simple wiki then I don't think much of these gods.

Comment: @Servy: I'm sorry, I meant that I'm always met with people who are *hugely* invested in SO and the way things are. And by "ignored" I mean that I don't have a single upvote, even for a comment that goes along with what seems to be the prevalent philosophy. Meanwhile, familiar names are getting many upvotes just for wearing the SO badge. This is no democracy

Comment: @Borodin _"It's bizarre how there are so many ways in which SO seems broken, and requires me to dig into the inner workings to fathom what some things mean."_ Um.... [The help center had this listed under "Asking", third link.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) Would've helped you a lot with this question of yours, and no "digging" required. Just reading a help center page. As for SO seeming "broken", you'll have to be more detailed because most of us here don't see any issues. (GIve us some proof of problems, then we'll be able to see them.)

Comment: @Magisch: *"I think you're taking this too seriously"* I'm happy to be disagreed with, but all I've heard is *that's the way things are, do you want to upset the status quo* without offering a real solution to the question

Comment: @Kendra: That should be on the top-level UI, unless you went to a different school from me? The biggest problem is that the decision to alter the subject line of off-line questions with `[on hold]` without a mouse-over. Changing the data of a post is madness. I could easily have a question called `[on hold][on hold]`

Comment: @Borodin I'm not sure what you mean. The help center is linked on every page, and the landing page to the help center has that link listed third in the "Asking" section. If you mean the help center link should be more obvious, I'd agree that sure, the link to help could definitely be more obvious. If you mean something else, I'm afraid I don't follow.

Comment: @Borodin Apologies if that hasn't come through clearly yet, but if you propose a feature change, you need broad community support, and to get that, you need to identify what you percieve the issue to be, identify what you would do to fix it, and provide arguments how your solution would have a positive impact on the site. The process of changing things on SO is slow and every feature has to be very deliberately vetted before being implemented.

Comment: @Borodin And as to the current answers, most of them are asking about "why would your way be better?" or "How does this improve things?" or "Have you considered the consequences?" None of which come through clearly in the OP atm

Comment: @Magisch: I can provide that. Can you confirm that the *only change* for a "deleted" question is that it is unable to receive answers and that it has ` [on hold]` appended to its subject line?

Comment: In the mean time, is there any problem with me re-posting the question myself and answering my own question? In the past that seems to be the only way to get a revised question noticed, despite the measures that are supposed to be in place

Comment: @Borodin There are a few smaller subtle things, for instance only closed questions with non-positive score and no positively scored answers are eligible for auto deletion, and only closed questions can have delete votes cast against them. Aside from that, a closed question counts a little heavier against you when it comes to question bans. But none of those are major. The major effect is that answers are blocked.

Comment: @Borodin I don't know and I can't stop you, but it may get closed as a duplicate if the approach isn't sufficiently different.

Comment: @Borodin Reading your edit, I believe I understand your issue. The "[on hold]" part of a question is explained in the banner attached to the question. If you want an explanation in the _question list_ then that's going to be a bit noisy. A tooltip is a potential idea, yes, but the information is already in the help center (which users are expected to read in the first place (yes, I know, most don't)) and the close/on-hold banner links to the help center. The tooltip could/would likely be too small for an explanation of question closure. As for "changing the data", I feel I can't answer that

Comment: @Kendra: Thanks, but providing a glob of documentation and saying *"it's in the documentation"* is horribly old-fashioned and I hoped for better from SO. The UI should explain why certain actions are unavailable as well as preventing them from being requested. We have all come across a greyed-out option and had to google for the reason. A site design should make impossible actions unavaialable *together with the reason why*. I am not happy to be told that, had I read the Britannica, all would be clear

Comment: There is still far too much upvoting for comments that defend the status quo above anything else. Nothing will ever be changed with roadies like these

Comment: @Borodin Its one of the pitfalls of being a large site. People like familiarity and changes on a massive side come slowly, with alot of inertia. I've run into this in the past, but I can't say I disagree much with it anymore.

Comment: @Borodin I already said that a banner is placed on "on hold" and "closed" questions to explain why. If you find that banner to be lacking, open a feature request to improve it, explain what's wrong, and how your suggestion will be better. The UI already does explain why a question can't be answered. Explaining how closure works is best handled by the help center. SO does well at explaining why you can't do thing- If you can't edit, there is a tooltip explaining why. If you can't answer, there is a banner on the question explaining why. If you can't review, there is a banner on the top, etc.

Comment: @Borodin Why does it surprise you that people like the site the way that it is?  Were you expecting everyone on the site to hate the way everything works?  Did you consider the possibility that people are in support of question closure not being removed because they actually like the concept of questions being closed when they're unanswerable (or don't belong here) rather than supporting it purely because that's how the site works?  If everyone using the site was fundamentally opposed to the sites core features, they wouldn't all be here using the site.

Comment: @Kendra: Take a look, for instance at [q37835435](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835435). There is no "banner". `[on hold]` has been appended to the subject line, and mousing over it gives be just a link back to the same question, which is useless. The next link comes all the way at the end of the question, and is to *How to Ask*. Then there is `If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question` some of those words are links, but don't look to be priority ones ...

Comment: @Kendra: ... In fact by far the major links are to the profiles of the five subscribers who voted for the closure, again completely useless

Comment: @Borodin At the bottom of the question, with the names of the close voters, is the banner and the explanation of why the question was closed. _"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."_ That is given to help the OP reword their question. There is a link that says "help center" that goes to the page I linked above, a link to edit the question and, yes, a link to "How to Ask" to help the OP fix the post.

Comment: @Servy: *"Were you expecting everyone on the site to hate the way everything works?"* is just nonsense, and I wonder why you wrote it. I'm not surprised that people enjoy the status quo, but rather that that any change, however minor, and however little it may affect their experience, is opposed with such furious and insubstantial upvoting of the defenders

Comment: @Borodin (cont.) Once again, if you feel that banner needs improved, open a question about it. If you continue to refuse to accept that that banner is in any way helpful, I'm afraid I won't change your mind and I have nothing more to do here.

Comment: @Borodin You think that abolishing question closure is a minor change that won't affect anyone's experience on the site?  That's just nonsense and I wonder why you wrote it.

Comment: @Kendra: Ah so *that* is your banner! Do you have any web designers on your team? At the focus of the page I see my subject line with `[on hold]` at the end. That doesn't sound so bad, although *deleted* would make me sit up. Why should I read through the question? I wrote it and I know what's there. If I stray to that yellow panel after my question, the biggest letters are telling me off, followed by links to the profiles of all those people better than me who voted to close my question. In smaller text there's stuff that amounts to *please see your probation officer once a week* So I go away

Comment: @Servy: No one said that *"abolishing question closure"* was a good idea, and I am sure that your comment to that effect was intentionally provocative. I am simply aghast that the only measures against poor questions are to block answers. System design anyone?

Comment: @Servy: Please explain this sentence *"Did you consider the possibility that people are in support of question closure not being removed because they actually like the concept of questions being closed when they're unanswerable (or don't belong here) rather than supporting it purely because that's how the site works?"*

Comment: @Borodin No, technically you just wanted to make question closure not actually prevent answers, which is it's primary purpose, resulting in question closure doing virtually nothing meaningful.  If you're going to have question closure not actually do anything, then you might as well just not have it.  Saying that you want questions to still get closed, but have question closure not do anything doesn't change my previous point; that's still not at all a minor change, and it's *absolutely* going to affect the experience of the users here.

Comment: @Servy: Say what?

Comment: @Borodin You were asserting that everyone's rejecting your proposal purely because it's a change from the status quo, rather than because they actually disagreed with it.  I was asserting that people are rejecting your proposal because they actually disagree with it, and feel that it would make the site worse to implement it.

Comment: @Borodin What do you not understand about the comment?

Comment: @Servy: If people had disagreed with my question then they could have posted an answer. Instead I two answers while multiple supporters cast ineffective votes for comments that they see as maintaining the status quo. Stack Overflow is far from perfect, and I believe it has become stuck in a bog. You could persuade me otherwise, but not by writing over-long sentences that even you can't explain

Comment: @Servy: That's irrelevant. I want to know what *you* understand by your comment

Comment: @Borodin So you're upset that more people didn't post answers all saying the same thing?  Why would seeing more answers saying the same thing help you?

Comment: @Kendra: It sounds like the best I can do is to talk about a modification to the UI where a question has been flagged as deleted. I'll submit something, but I still rail against sanctions for a questioner being applied to a prospective answerer.

Comment: @Servy: *"So you're upset that more people didn't post answers all saying the same thing?"* I have no idea where you got that from, and I suspect that you're drunk. Best wishes

Comment: @Borodin like on the main site: if i see an answer that is virtually what i would say/do, i upvote it. Posting my own answer isn't necessary, nor is commenting... At least until i have something to say. What do you prefer, people upvoting the status quo comments, or having 14 different users comment the same things to you? (Id like to also take a second to remind everyone to stay civil here? Attacks on people's grammar is just childish and helps no one...)

Comment: @Patrice: I would prefer that you explain yourself every time.To me upvotes say *I agree with that*, not that you have the same opinion yourself

Comment: @Borodin which i did, just now. If i have none and i just upvote comments that reflect how i feel.... Should i just not do anything? You seem to have gripe at the upvoted comments, but i genuinely don't see how any other approach would be better. You say "i understand upvotes [...] but if you have a point then you should make it". What if all the upvotes didnt have a point to make and just agreed? (Oh and if you really want me to start pointing out where this is derailing and who's being snarky at who.... I got better things to do,and so do you, most likely)

Comment: @Patrice: I just edited my comment, and I hope it explains. For me, upvoting a comment means something like *oh yeah, I hadn't thought of that, but they're right* while writing your own comment means *here's what I think*. I don't think your opinion can ever exactly match anyone else's. That's how trolls can make us agree while we disagree with their words

Comment: @Borodin for you, that's what it means. That's awesome! Votes are 100% personnal, and to me, upvoting a comment is (sorry for my French): "tu m'enleve les mots de la bouche". At the end of the day, people vote for what they want. All you know are the arguments of the user who posted the comments. If you dont like the number by the comment.... Im sure there's a userscript for that somewhere

Comment: @Patrice: Thank you, but it seems that we disagree. You say *"you took the words from my mouth"*, or perhaps *"that was on the tip of my tongue"*. And I'm sure you know that *"excuse my French"* is *"I'm sorry, but I'm going to swear"*. Mais un commentaire dit *"c'est mon idée"* pas *"je suis d'accord"*

Comment: @Borodin i like to use "excuse my French" when im about to use French with someone i'm not certain who knows it. I don't apologize for swearing. And we may disagree on what a vote is,but at the end of the day you won't know who upvoted the comment or for what. So if it bothers you to see the upvotes, just don't look at them. Inferring anything from them will just leave a terrible after taste... Like it seems to be doing now.(now... Got any arguments or something? If we discuss my weird use of languages, we are a) far from done, and b) not moving this forward)

Comment: @Patrice: The English idiom is that *"excuse my French"* is a preemptive apology for swearing, mais bien sûr, comment vous l'utilisez jusqu'à vous. Je pense juste que le vote est un accord avec une idée , pas ma propre idée.

Comment: @Patrice: Je crains que l'adoption des idées des autres nous empêche de penser

Comment: @Borodin Stack is English. Even as a French native, i limit how much i use it because it doesn't have its place here. And again,you go with "i think that voting is not MY idea, but me being in agreement with the idea".... But again, that's YOU. Unless you went to each upvoter who upvoted a comment, you won't know for sure why they did it. In any case, if i want to vote a comment because it's "close enough" to my own idea, it's MY prerogative to do so.

Comment: @Borodin and there is the likelyhood that just upvoting other ideas means my specific one isn't represented. It's also possible that my idea IS represented and that's why i upvote it. You wont know which one it is, and arguing to the fact is honestly pointless. In any case.... I will ask again: got a real argument here instead of "that's how I see it"? Because if not, i see no value in continuing this comment chain

Comment: @Petrice: Please post an answer of your own. I would like to read what you have to say beyond agreeing with other people

Answer (score 11):

I don't really hate this idea. Closing and reopening has rather a lot of overhead right now, and it'd be nice if folks with some experience could just blow past it. Got a gold badge in Perl? Fine, answer any question you want. If it's *too* bad, it'll end up deleted anyway, along with your answer, so there's some motivation to fix things too.

The easiest way to implement this would be to extend the current gold badge "hammer" privileges to *all* close reasons, thus allowing knowledgeable users to close and reopen whatever they want without resistance. Figuring out how to do that without opening the door to abuse is left to be determined.

Comment: I think this could be useful if it was based on the top participants of a given tag. Low traffic tags suffer from some large delay between closing/opening. But if you're in like [tag:java] or [tag:php], pretty much every question is gonna get its fair shake - imo.

Comment: I would like that closed, <3 scored questions are deleted even if the answer is upvoted/accepted. The answer & edit badges doesn't seems to be a very strong stimulator, but this one is better.

Comment: If we're going to let gold badgers reopen any question, if would be nice to require that they edit the post first, since 5 other people felt that it wasn't clear or up to standards.  Basically, you'd have to edit to put it in the reopen queue before you could reopen it.  Duplicate reopening seems like a special case, since it's often used to retarget the dupe.

Comment: There is also the issue that you can get a gold badge in a popular tag without knowing all that much about the technology itself. Take me as an example. If I was less scrupulous and answered more [tag:c] homework dumps, I could get the gold badge in some time (maybe a year or two or some more) without becoming any better at the actual coding. Under your system that would then grant me privileges to decide on the fate of questions alone. Our current process alleviates that by requiring a 5 vote consensus.

Comment: I like this idea, it would essentially deputize a very large amount of users who are dedicated to the site and sometimes (as seen by the OP here) feel like their voice or opinions have no weight. As far as the abuse metrics, I agree that is a valid concern, but I think that the overall weight of these users who are already vested in the interests of the site being applied even stronger would only be a benefit.

Comment: Looking at making it easier for top users to get a question reopened would be something I'm perfectly okay with, but letting such users answer a question *while keeping it closed* seems very wrong.  Either it's appropriate for the question to be answered, in which case the question should be reopened for anyone to answer, or it isn't, and it should remain closed.  Letting only certain people answer is rather contrary to the idea of a question being closed.

Comment: That's just a detail, @Servy. If you have the ability to instantly reopen any question in your area of expertise, then you have the ability to answer closed questions... The fact that they're not closed after you've done so is inconsequential to your goals. It *does* mean that you can't do it twice, but then again very few people answer questions twice anyway.

Comment: @Shog9 It doesn't matter to *you*, as an answerer.  It matters *significantly* to others who comes along later to see the question, and possibly answer it.  It also matters to the roomba, it affects the question author's post-ban standing, it affects the impression of future readers as to whether this question is an appropriate question or not, etc.  Unless you're asserting that if  you gave these users binding close-reopen votes you'd find lots of people reopening such questions, answering them, and then re-closing them.

Comment: @Servy - I thought the point of his comment was that by answering you implicitly reopen the question, thereby allowing other users to also answer if they were so inclined making it fair.

Comment: That *might* happen, @Servy... Although by doing so you'd essentially be nominating your own answer for deletion, so I don't know if it'd be as common as we might fear. Truth is, we had a lot of concerns about abuse when implementing the dup-hammer that mostly didn't play out in practice; turns out folks with gold badges tend to be fairly invested in the site.

Comment: @TravisJ The statement that it's "inconsequential" as to whether or not the question is closed after the answer is posted lead me to believe Shog didn't care either way, rather than that he felt it was important that such a user posting an answer would implicitly reopen the question.  If I'm misreading it, I'd be quite glad to be corrected.

Comment: @Servy _"The fact that they're not closed after you've done so is inconsequential to your goals."_ I'm not sure what you read there, but it reads to me as _"As the answerer, you're not going to care that the question's now opened since you've answered it."_ as in, once you answer the question it'll be opened.

Comment: @Kendra The fact that an answerer wouldn't care if it's open or not doesn't imply that it would be opened.  Shog, if you care to clarify, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I really don't think it makes a whole lot of difference, @Servy... But if (as I suggested here) this was implemented as binding close+reopen votes, reopening the question as part of answering would be a natural outcome.

Comment: @Shog9 Does your data wizardry indicate that you could afford that amount of trust to gold badge holders reliably? I'm afraid that some of them don't agree with the goals of the site in almost entirety and giving them tools with such impact could be harmful.

Comment: Yes, but carbonic acid aside I think it could work.

Comment: @Shog9 Mhm. I'll begrudingly defer to your ability to analyse data and your judgement then.

Comment: @Shog9 _"to extend the current gold badge "hammer" privileges to **all close reasons**"_ I've been considering several times to ask for a feature to extend the _mjölnir powers_, but certainly not for _all close reasons_ only those that are really related to the (language) tag (e.g. questions asking for _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")"_ or _"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."_).

Comment: @Shog9 [Do you have an opinion (answer, alternative proposal) here?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326250/would-it-be-useful-to-have-an-extension-of-mj%c3%b6lnir-close-voting-powers-for-lang). I'd be really interested to read it, if so.

Answer (score 8):

Closure (and on hold by relation) provide a path for removing and hiding questions that do not belong at Stack Overflow. Either because they are off topic, or because they do not align with the outlook of the site.

Part of that path is to prevent answers. This both discourages questions which are not a good fit here as well as saves the time of users who are answering the question from wasting their time on a post that will be removed or hidden.

I feel the latter part of this is what has affected you here, and that is unfortunate. No one likes to waste their time, and that is why so many efforts have been made to close questions faster thus giving an earlier signal to not answer them. The unfortunate side effect of not being effective enough at closing down questions deserving of closure is that often user's time is wasted.

With the drive to protect quality and at least attempt to not be a quantity over quality site, sometimes there are posts which had deserved a chance but did not get one. While there is the FGITW for answering, there is also the same mentality for closing; and just like sometimes answering quickly gets it wrong, closing quickly can also get it wrong.

One such suggestion that I have seen to possibly alleviate this would be to also weigh in a post's score with the closure metric - but I believe that would simply make these types of posts closed ever faster.

In such a situation as you find yourself in now, where you have spent a considerable amount of time researching and are clearly a knowledgeable person, instead of reflecting on the downsides of the system take your research and post it so that others may find it.

As you indicate with regards to editing, you are aware of the underlying issue. I believe this places you in a far better position to frame the problem, and as a result I would suggest creating a canonical post for that situation. This would allow you to eloquently frame the problem while at the same time providing the research that you have already gathered. It will create a well informed post that can stand the test of time, and also you may leave it as a link in a comment to the closed post if you wish in order to provide a path of information for the OP.

Creating a canonical is the best of both worlds option here in my opinion, and if the situation does not deserve this type of approach, perhaps the question should just remain closed and left for removal as was its original path.

Comment: _"saves the time of users who are answering the question from wasting their time on a post that will be removed or hidden."_ - maybe the screen should start shaking more furiously for every closevote that is cast while you are typing an answer, as to let you know something bad is about to happen.

Comment: @CodeCaster - And perhaps a little smoke can start to appear, that leads to crinkling and then like an all out fire in the corner that slowly burns the page away?

Answer (score 0):

I'd tend to favor this, not so much because saving such a question is necessarily worthwhile, but to encourage better answers.

On several occasions I've put quite a bit of time into writing (what I thought was) a really good answer, then tried to post the answer, and couldn't because the question had been closed. Some of those questions probably were marginal, but probably would have been acceptable if coupled with really good answers. Others honestly were good questions, but were (apparently) a bit beyond the understanding of most of the readers (well, at least 5 of them, anyway).

In any case, it seems to me that this has exactly the opposite of the effect we (should) want. Putting lots of effort into writing great answers is punished. Instead, it encourages writing short answers to simple questions with a minimum of thought.

As an aside: this is also one of the reasons the rep cap is such a lousy idea. Essentially every user close to the top of the rep ladder hits the rep cap nearly ever day--therefore, differences in reputation are determined almost exclusively by the number of answers accepted. So, for anybody who cares about reputation even slightly, the behavior that's encouraged is to produce a large number of fairly decent answers, rather than a few really great answers<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1. And yes, a played that game well enough for long enough to speak from experience about this. At one time I was in the top 30 (or so) users by rep. I've since dropped quite a bit, largely *because* I decided to concentrate on making contributions I thought were more meaningful and useful.</sup>

Comment: *Putting lots of effort into writing great answers is punished* Indeed! *Others honestly were good questions, but were (apparently) a bit beyond the understanding of most of the readers (well, at least 5 of them, anyway).* Makes me want to wish for an alternative to SO

Answer (score -12):

While the close system often works well, and many suspended or closed questions actually *are* unclear and/or unanswerable in their current state, this isn't always true.  Sometimes, in rare cases, a question may be unclear to some people, but be perfectly clear to others.  In these cases, it would be useful to allow people who can understand the question to post answers, because those answers could potentially help make the question itself clearer.

To this end, a possible solution would be to create a "potentially unclear" or "subjectively unclear" suspend reason, which has a special mechanism attached:

- If a question is marked as potentially unclear, then users are allowed to answer it.  However, this answer will not be shown immediately.  Instead, whenever a potentially unclear question is edited OR answered, it is placed in the reopen queue.  If reviewers feel that this answer makes the question clear, or at the very least that the answer could plausibly be valid for what the question appears to be *trying* to ask, then they can reopen the question, at which case the answer will go through and be posted.
- If a user answers a potentially unclear question, they will receive a prompt similar to:

  > "You appear to understand what this question is asking.  Would you like to edit it for clarity?"

  If they choose to do so, this would make it more likely that the question is reopened, due to other users actually being able to understand what was being asked.

Note that if a "potentially unclear" question is answered and put on the reopen queue, that the answer would only be posted if people vote to reopen the question.  If they vote for it to remain closed, the answer would be discarded.  This system would thus act as a supplement to the current "edit, then we vote on whether to reopen" system, for cases where people aren't entirely sure that editing is necessary for the question to be understandable.

Comment: or... they could, you know, edit it to be more clear, get it reopened, and *then* answer it. Isn't there even a badge that promotes this?

Comment: @KevinB The problem with that is that often, these fringe cases are often complex, and writing a good answer takes a while.  And during the time spent answering, the question will most likely have been closed.  This idea is mainly designed to counter that, by letting the person who actually _did_ understand it well enough to answer give a significant amount of input on it (and thus influence others' understanding of it, ideally for the better), while also prompting them to make the question clearer for those of us that couldn't tell what it means.

Comment: Also, the term "potentially unclear" is to indicate that the people who voted it closed don't understand it themselves, but feel that others _would_ be able understand it enough to answer it without it having to be edited first.  This contrasts with the normal "unclear", which indicates that the people who voted it closed don't understand it, and don't feel that it can be understood well enough to answer in its current state.

Comment: right, but, the issue is that these.. "unclear" questions are often duplicates, but they're just so unclear that they can't be accurately closed as such. closing them and preventing answers saves the time of the answerer.

Comment: @KevinB Then they would be marked as "unclear", and closed normally.  I'm not suggesting that we replace "unclear" as a close reason, but rather that we add an additional reason that basically means "We think this is unclear, but aren't entirely sure."  It would only be used in cases where it's at least _plausible_ that the question would be understandable to some users, and where the question doesn't appear to be a duplicate.

Comment: .... who would use that... if the question is unclear, it's unclear... what close reason would it replace?

Comment: @KevinB I imagine it would mainly be used in extremely complex cases, or ones where the post is horribly mangled, but appears to be _trying_ to ask a valid question.  One case that definitely comes to mind is the one in the OP's second paragraph, where a post is made by a non-native English speaker, and users have to spend time untangling the Engrish to figure out what they actually mean.  These are in and of themselves unclear, but may very well be entirely answerable if someone _is_ able to piece together the actual question.

Comment: Thankfully we have this wonderful "on hold" grace period.

Comment: @KevinB Good point, I forgot about that.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem entirely though, you can't post answers during the grace period (which I think should remain.) I like shog's idea related to simply giving the power users more moderation power.

Comment: Part of the reasoning for this idea was that if the "potentially unclear" question still isn't considered to be clear, even after someone answers, then their answer won't be posted, and the question would remain closed.  It would thus act as a supplement to the current "edit, then we vote on whether to reopen" system, for cases where people aren't entirely sure that editing is necessary for the question to be understandable.  Not sure if this would be worth the effort to implement, though.

Comment: Edited that in, since I don't think I made it clear.

Comment: tbh i didn't read the whole answer before responding, didn't realize you were suggesting a new close reason. Maybe... if the user attempts to answer a question that is closed as 'unclear' they get said prompt.

Comment: @KevinB That's a pretty good idea, actually.  It would likely be difficult to determine what posts are unclear to everyone, and which are unclear, but still make sense to some users, meaning that a "potentially unclear" close reason would likely be hard to use properly; I didn't really think about that when suggesting this, though.

Comment: Modifying the system so that if someone attempts to answer a closed-as-unclear question, they're prompted to edit the question for clarity, would actually work pretty well with that badge you mentioned; the system could possibly even be modified to cache their answer, and post it if the question is reopened or discard it if it isn't.  [In this case, if they don't edit it for clarity, the answer probably just wouldn't go through at all, as normal for closed questions.]