# Is there a problem with the grace period for answering closed questions?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, closed-questions

A few minutes ago, I stumbled on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27552353/464709). It was initially a homework question with no attempt at solving the problem shown, and was rightfully closed a few minutes later.

<sup>(The questioner subsequently added code, so it *may* be a candidate for reopening, but that's not what I want to discuss here.)</sup>

Later, to my surprise, the question received [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27552628/464709). Quality of the answer aside, it was posted a whopping *16 minutes* after the question was closed.

I thought the grace period for answering closed questions was far shorter, and I believe allowing such a wide delay undermines the meaning of closing. Is there a problem with this feature, or am I just too harsh here?

Comment: I'm guessing, but the answerer may have started answering the question before it was closed. Even if it took him a while to complete the answer, since it began before the gate went down, it was allowed.

Comment: Or we can just delete the question. That should solve everything. :)

Comment: If the community deems that a question is inappropriate, you should not be allowed to undermine this by posting an answer.  I don't know why we even have a grace period.

Comment: @Hovercraft, it looks you're right, I searched around as I didn't know that feature existed and [found out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79434/164403) the window in this situation is about *four hours* (ouch). Now I don't know what to do, because the duplicate is on the Overmeta. Should I try to duplicate the answer here?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi for reference, [it was not the OP who edited the question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27552353/2).

Comment: @Chris, I know, I was there. The questioner posted their code in a comment and [a brave soul](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/) edited it back in the question. That would have been to much detail for *this* question, though :)

Comment: Worst of all, a very low quality *"give me da codez"* question has received a *"here is da codez"* answer and there is a net gain in rep to the answerer until the answer gets 15 downvotes.

Comment: @Matt, yup, we have quite a worst-case there. The answer *could* have been good, though, and there's not much more we can do for this specific case. Piling downvotes may be tempting but I don't believe it would bring anything (apart from the answerer possibly complaining here, which will only fuel the fire). Better move on, as always...

Comment: The potential duplicate explains that the grace period exists, but doesn't say how long it is, so I think this is a subtly different question.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam: the grace period is [4 hours](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254819/user-answering-the-question-after-it-is-closed/254820#254820). We can re-dupe this to my post instead, if you insist..

Comment: @MartijnPieters I doubt it's worth it now - I handled it from the review queue so just thought my "Leave open" was worth a comment.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, I agree the dupe target isn't ideal at all. OP knows that there's a grace period.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: we can add multiple targets now, so I added it in.

Comment: that's good too.

Answer (score 16):

According to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79434/164403) on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), if a user starts composing their answer before the question is closed, and ignores the warning messages they receive as soon as the question is closed, *and* works around the disabled submit button, then the grace period becomes around 4 hours.

Therefore, this behavior is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

That said, allowing such a large grace period while warning the user and disabling the submit button does not make much sense to me. Dropping this feature may not be a bad idea.

Upon further digging, there is another possible explanation. [Tim Stone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/150235/tim-stone) says in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91928/164403) that mobile app users are not subject to any restriction at all, and basically benefit from an infinite grace period in this situation. We may want to do something about that (at least if this phenomenon becomes more common).

Comment: Yes, no ambivalence here. If there is a grace period it should not be concealed half-heartedly. Man! I wish I had known this, I've seen my efforts go down the drain a couple of times. As for me, the grace period should be much shorter (an hour?) but visible.

Comment: @Gert, one hour? I was thinking about something like 5 minutes ;) Since the user is warned that the question has been closed, and will be able to edit their answer once posted, they shouldn't need more than that: either most of their answer is there and they can quickly finish it, post it and then edit it at their leisure, or they just started writing and losing the answer is not that big a problem.

Comment: Ten minutes, OK? :)

Comment: @Gert, sold :) -

Comment: If you see the warning, who will stop you posting the answer as it is and edit it to complete it?

Comment: @msrd0, early downvotes on the incomplete answer, presumably (not all of us have the time to go back and revert our downvotes when the answer is later expanded). The warning is the current behavior, so users are already able to do that.