# Dupe-hammer: Remove grace period for posting an answer

Tags: feature-request, answers, duplicate-questions, dupehammer, grace-period

When you close a question as duplicate with the gold-badge dupehammer, there's a grace period in which users can still answer said question.

For obvious duplicates, (familiar questions, well-known answers), this often means multiple answers will slip in, after the question is closed.

[Here's a recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46466513/). As you can see, the dupe hammer was applied before any of the answers were submitted, yet three answers got through, the last one submitted 3 minutes after closing the question.

---

My request is to *drastically* reduce this grace period, or even remove it altogether.

Answers on hammered duplicates typically add nothing new to the subject. The answer in the dupe target is usually more elaborate.
The answers *do* prevent downvoted duplicates from [being deleted automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).

For "non-hammer" closures, the grace period (arguably) isn't that much of a problem, because those closures usually get applied after people have had a chance to get an answer in.

Edit:

- [Here is yet another example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47302407/). ***15*** minutes passed after the closure. (That late [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47302919/1835379) has now been deleted)
- [Or this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50463156), 5 minutes passed.

That's just absurd. What's the point in closing these questions as *duplicate* if users can still answer them?

Comment: I didn't think the grace period is close reason specific... (not 100% sure on that though)

Comment: @JonClements: Other close reasons usually aren't applied as fast as a dupe hammer. People that want to get an answer in usually have time to do so, for the other reasons.

Comment: I've seen too broad/no mcve applied quicker than it takes for someone to find an appropriate less common duplicate. But that's an aside - my point is that I don't believe dupe closures are special cased for the grace period and don't see why this wouldn't apply to all close reasons... An answer getting snuck in after it's closed as a tool request or POB is in the same ball park, right?

Comment: @JonClements: Actually, you're right. Only the timing is (arguably) different.  Why differentiate the closure type when the point is to prevent new answers on closed questions...

Comment: What is the problem that you're trying to solve here? If the problem is that upvoted answers to duplicate questions prevents the questions from being deleted, then maybe you need to feature request *that* be changed, instead. In other words, this looks like an XY problem.

Comment: @CodyGray: Votes on the answers don't matter to the roomba. The fact that it's answered prevents the roomba from deleting the question. So no, not an XY problem. See the _"30 days old"_ section in the [Roomba page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) I linked.

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't believe there is a difference between close reasons for grace timings.. I think it's just more likely it *feels* like there is because you see it immediately closed with the hammer and answers come in... If you're not the last close voter for other reasons you probably aren't actively paying as much attention to the page as when you've just hammered something.

Comment: @Cerbrus: But *[i]f the question was closed more than 9 days ago* the roomba deletes a question even *with answers* provided the post *has no answers with a score > 0*

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The 9-day roomba rule does not apply to duplicate closures: _"not closed as a duplicate"_

Comment: @Cerbrus: crumbs.

Comment: I looked at the exact same thing Martijn did. Good to know that we are all consistent...ly wrong. :-)

Comment: Hey, at least there's no public disagreement between mods :D

Comment: Backing up, why is this a problem that needs fixing?  We get questions that describe a problem differently with a link providing juice to a canonical answer, plus variant answers in this particular duplicate.  Duplicates are supposed to provide juice and alternative explanations to their canonical Q&A.

Comment: I'm confused. Is there a special grace period for dupehammered questions or is this the normal [grace period](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280667/is-there-a-problem-with-the-grace-period-for-answering-closed-questions)? If it's the normal are you suggesting to make a special shorter grace period for those questions? From what I saw gold-badgers are in many cases unjustly closing questions that are not actually duplicates and if anything their power should be decreased, definitely not increased.

Comment: @Oleg: this comes from obvious duplicates I close often getting multiple answers after being closed. Those answers are counter-productive. Originally, I wrote this request so it only applies to dupe hammers, but the grace period isn't different for other close reasons.

Comment: @Yakk: _"Answers on hammered duplicates typically add nothing new to the subject. The answer in the dupe target is usually more elaborate. The answers do prevent downvoted duplicates from being deleted automatically."_ Those answer are actively harming SO's content / searchability.

Comment: @cerebus Please provide evidence it harms searchability.  The juice flows towards the dupe target...

Comment: The fact that that our dupe tree is growing deeper and deeper? Preferably, we don't want search to return any duplicates at all, but now, we're often getting more signposts than actual dupe targets in search. For example, yet another _"How to return a value from this async function"_ question in JavaScript only dilutes that topic with another pointer to the dupe. Oh, and it's "Cerbrus".

Comment: If people systematically downvoted those answers to duplicates, sooner or later nobody would dare to answer a duplicate any more.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: I like your optimism. But as long as a single upvote cancels out 5 downvotes, downvotes really aren't having the impact we may want them to have.

Comment: This happened to me few weeks ago when I closed a question and confused the heck out of me. Now, I know it's a feature.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Not to mention answer downvotes cost you rep and upvotes don't.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Ignoring the quality of answer and just dv because it's there. Wouldn't that be on the edge of misusing votes? Further, if someone seeks help and finds such a dup question with a downvoted answer, they will probably think it is wrong even if it is high quality. And the credibility of the site... a high quality answer with downvotes must look strange to a visitor. I'm not sure I like the idea. IMO a vote must be a vote on the actual quality - not a punishment for doing something others don't like. The latter must be dealt with in another way.

Comment: @4386427: The downvote button says: _"This answer is not useful"_. Answers on duplicates that get asked multiple times each week _aren't_ useful.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest *“If people systematically downvoted those answers to duplicates […]”* – But that doesn’t happen. I regularly hammer questions on the C# tag where 3 or more answers slipped through and easily accumulate 2 or more upvotes (even *after* closing). Worst part is that even very high rep users participate in this instead of actually searching for a duplicate. – There should be an incentive for not answering questions but closing them as duplicate instead. And maybe even for deleting answers after a question has been closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @poke I'm in the C# tag too and see the same thing. Some will even get mad if you comment telling them not to answer (obvious) duplicates...

Comment: @Cerbrus *"Answers on duplicates that get asked multiple times each week aren't useful."* - If only people would vote for what is good for the progression of the site and therefore the world, and not for what they feel right there and then in the moment.

Comment: @Gimby: we can hope...

Comment: @Cerbrus I like your optimism :)

Comment: I do wonder what the benefit of the grace period is at all. Either we allow posting answers on closed questions or we don't. Either way, 15 minutes seems, well, broken.

Comment: @DavidG: A point _could_ be made for potential abuse by hammering a question you just answered, but that's very unlikely to happen, and easily handled by banning the user for obvious misbehavior. So, hardly any benefit.

Comment: Well possibly, but that is saying we don't trust gold badge owners to be responsible users of the site.

Comment: @DavidG: exactly. It's a silly unlikely possible benefit of the grace period.

Comment: That grace period has been added just recently or not? I don't remember that being possible, say, one year ago.

Comment: @Evk It has always been possible.  It's easier to do (particularly by accident) when using the mobile site, so as mobile usage has grown you see it a bit more, but it has always been a thing.  Additionally, as more people learn about it and start to abuse it usage for desktop users grows as well.

Comment: @DavidG Part of the stated reason was that they didn't want people's answers just swallowed up if they were most of the way through writing it when the question is closed, but that's easily solved by just leaving the answer's content on the page as a draft.  (The primary use case here would be so that they can post the answer on the canonical if it really is a better solution than any that had been provided before, or so that they can save it in the event that the post gets reopened).

Comment: @Servy Indeed, so there's a fairly trivial fix to prevent loss of work which seems a lot cleaner than adding a grace period

Comment: 1/2 Here's why there SHOULD be a grace period (and notification that the question was just closed): your answer might be made in good faith (not just for rep hunting from a frequently asked question). Such an answer might be useful (providing a new fresh take on the issue) and it might be difficult to retailor to the duplicate target. Then without a grace period, some such good faith answers will get through and some get told "sorry, the work you've put this answer won't get accepted unlike the answer submitted 2 seconds ago, because 1 second ago, the question got closed"

Comment: 2/2  Lack of such a grace period alienates good-faith contributors to the site and is unfair to those whose answer got through vs whose answer didn't. Some parts of SO (seems to be centered around particular programming languages) may have a cultural problem with cheap bad-faith (rep-whoring) answers. Then I think such communities should self-police themselves through comments and downvotes but not through a mechanism (or lack of a machanism) that alienates good-faith contributors elsewhere.

Comment: Aside from this question being _old_, your comment doesn't relate to this scenario, @PSkocik. Those answers take more than a minute to write. This question is about obvious dupes that get hammered very quickly. Questions like that _don't_ get significant answers. It's always short FGITW answers that have been posted time and time again already.