# Question answered 3h10m after closing?

Tags: support, closed-questions, late-answers

[Question history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63686032/timeline):

- 10:38Z: Question posted
- 10:52Z: Question closed
- 14:02Z: Answer posted

How can this happen? I think I remember there was some leeway that when a question gets closed while you're typing your answer, you can still post "through" the closure, but more than three hours later?

Comment: Yes, more than three hours later.  It's one of the worst lingering bugs on SO.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252711/this-answer-was-posted-after-the-question-was-closed-how-is-that-possible

Comment: And https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280667

Comment: Four hours it is, thanks.

Comment: It's a bug in any case.  Sometimes you'll get a grace period, but other times you'll get one of those banner bars almost immediately after closure that says "This post has been closed... No more answers will be accepted."  I could understand if there's some algorithm that dispenses with the grace period for crappy questions (i.e. negative votes), but it's never been properly explained.

Comment: It's buggy for sure, more than once I've not received the "closed"-banner while the question was being closed while typing an answer, and vice versa.

Comment: Note that from Oded (SO employee at the time) in 2017: "*The window is about that wide, a few hours, @user6910411" – Oded Oct 7 '17 at 19:44*